# Class template specialization that changes only one member function

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

I have a class template `Function` that takes a unsigned integer as a template argument, for the number of inputs. This template overloads `operator()` so the `Function` can be evaluated for a set of given inputs.

Usually, one of the prototypes for this member would be `operator()(double, ...)`. However, if the template argument is 0, then that prototype wouldn't work, as it requires at least one argument.

```
template <unsigned Arity>
struct Function {
    void operator () (double, ...);
};
```

Normally, I'd just write a template specialization, but there would be a *lot* of redundant code since there are a lot of other member functions. Again, normally, I'd make a base class containing the redundant code for the main class definition and the specialization to inherit from.

```
struct FunctionBase {
    // Common code
    Function operator + (Function const &) const; // ?
};

template <unsigned Arity>
struct Function : FunctionBase { /* etc */ };
```

Unfortunately, I'm unsure how to go about doing this, since for example `operator+` is meant to return a `Function`. But how can it do this if `Function` is only defined later on? `Function` inherits from the base class, and by this design `operator+` is in the base class...

It could return an instance of the base class, but then we need a way to convert that instance to an instance of `Function`, and I know of no way to do this without copying the first instance's data, which is very expensive in terms of performance.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: C++ is hard. If you want to have any hope of getting good suggestions, you have to include a concrete example of what you want to do, in your question; and specifically point out all the bits that cannot be changed. This is too vague. The starting point is: "you can't specialize a single class method, you have to specialize the whole class". So you need to find a workaround. Post some code, first.

Comment: That's one hefty paragraph. Regardless: you can very well forward-declare a class, use its type as return type in a function declaration, define the class, and define the function, all in that order.

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. Unless you edit your post to improve it, it probably will be voted to close. See [ask].

Comment: the answer is always: "composition"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is quite difficult to answer for it's far from being clear.
Below two possibile alternatives that try to address your issues:

- If you want to go ahead with `Arity` template parameter, you can use sfinae'd operators to deal with `Arity` equal to 0:

  ```
  #include<iostream>

  template<int Arity>
  struct Function {
      template<int N = Arity>
      std::enable_if_t<N == 0> operator()() {
          std::cout << "arity == 0" << std::endl;
      }

      template<int N = Arity>
      std::enable_if_t<N != 0> operator()(double, ...) {
          std::cout << "arity != 0" << std::endl;
      }
  };

  int main() {
      Function<0> f1;
      Function<2> f2;

      f1();
      f2(0., 42);
  }
  ```

  This way you no longer need to introduce a base class and all the related problems don't apply anymore.
- If you mind changing approach instead, you can switch to the following pattern for your function object:

  ```
  template<typename>
  struct Function;

  template<typename R, typename... A>
  struct Function<R(A...)> {
      R operator()(A... args) {
          // ...
      }

      // ...
  };
  ```

  You can use it as it follows:

  ```
  Function<void(int, char)> f;
  ```

  If you want to have a fixed `double` as you first parameter for `operator()`, you can do this:

  ```
  template<typename R, typename... A>
  struct Function<R(double, A...)> {
      R operator()(double d, A... args) {
          // ...
      }

      // ...
  };
  ```

  And use it as it follows:

  ```
  Function<void(double, int, char)> f1;
  Function<void(double)> f1;
  ```

  This will help at least dealing easily with empty parameter packs (note that `sizeof...(A)` will return you the number of submitted parameters in any case).

  It follows a minimal, working example implementation:

  ```
  #include<iostream>

  template<typename>
  struct Function;

  template<typename R, typename... A>
  struct Function<R(A...)> {
      R operator()(A... args) {
          int _[] = { 0, (std::cout << args << std::endl, 0)... };
          (void)_;
      }

      template<typename... O>
      Function<R(A..., O...)> operator+(Function<R(O...)>) {
          return {};
      }

      // ...
  };

  int main() {
      Function<void(int)> f1;
      Function<void(double)> f2;

      f1(42);
      f2(0.);
      (f1+f2)(3, .3);
  }
  ```